# Charles Proxy, SSL Proxying, host allowed, but requests are still encrypted

Tags: ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

when i click on the host item, it says: *"SSL Proxying enabled for this host"*
[image: SSL proxying enabled for host]

but when i try to see the requests, it says: *"SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations"*
[image: SSL proxying not working for requests]

in my settings, i have added some hosts to try to get this to work.
[image: SSL proxying settings]

it will work if i enable the wildcard "`*`", but i don't want to do that. i only want to enable SSL proxying to specific hosts, because if i enable for all, then some requests to other hosts will fail, because they are outside of my control, and i cannot configure all of them to trust my certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the host name is not enough; IP addresses of the hosts need to be added, too:

1. in list view, select item of interest; in the detail view, copy their host name

   [image: select domain, then copy the host name]
2. one at a time, go through each of the sub items, and copy the IP address (don't include the port number) of the "Remote Address" field

   [image: copy the "remote address" of each sub item of interest]
3. add all the IP addresses copied and domain names copied in the earlier steps to the `Proxy` > `SSL Proxying Settings` > `SSL Proxying` > `Include` list, then press "OK"

   [image: add all the copied IP addresses and host names to the SSL Proxying "include" list]
4. clear the current session's data

   [image: clear the current session's data]
5. done! all traffic captured from now on will be decrypted!